# How to group by two conditions in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

How to make a query like this with MongoDB and PHP: (ex. in SQL)

```
SELECT SUM(visits),* FROM db_name WHERE name = 'john' GROUP BY date
```

I wanna show all dates with sum of visits all persons with name is John.

And I stuck with this:

```
$test = $collection->aggregate([
    [ '$match' => [ "user" => "john" ]],
    [ '$group' => [ "_id" => null, "VISITS" => ['$sum'=>1]  ]],
]
);

foreach ($test as $row){
echo 'DATE:'.$row['DATE'].' VISITS:'.$row['VISITS'].'<br>';
}
```

The result should look like this:

```
DATE: 2022-01-01 VISITS: 4
DATE: 2022-01-02 VISITS: 1
DATE: 2022-01-03 VISITS: 0
DATE: 2022-01-04 VISITS: 7
DATE: 2022-01-05 VISITS: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

The `_id` field in your `$group` stage corresponds to what you use in `GROUP BY` in SQL. So, if you want to group by the date field, you'd use:

```php
$test = $collection->aggregate([
    ['$match' => ['user' => 'John']],
    ['$group' => ['_id' => '$date', 'visits' => '$sum' => 1]],
]);
```

If you need to use multiple fields in your group (i.e. the equivalent to `GROUP BY date, user`), use a document to do this:

```php
$test = $collection->aggregate([
    ['$group' => [
        '_id' => ['date' => '$date', 'user' => '$user'],
        'visits' => ['$sum' => 1],
    ]],
]);
```